# Enterprise manager failed to start in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, startup, oracle-enterprise-manager, oracle-10g-r2

I am using oracle 10g with 4 instance with same server but one of them has failed to start Oracle Enterprise Manager and rest of three are working fine.

```
Starting Oracle Enterprise Manager 10g Database Control
.................................................................... 
failed. 
Logs are generated in directory /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/vvs/sysman/log
```

Here I posted error log file -> **emagent.log**

```
2018-07-31 11:10:55 Thread-4124031232 Starting Agent 10.1.0.6.0 from /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1 (00701)
2018-07-31 11:10:55 Thread-4124031232 Starting Agent 10.1.0.6.0 from /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1 (00701)
2018-07-31 11:18:41 Thread-4124375296 Starting Agent 10.1.0.6.0 from /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1 (00701)
2018-07-31 11:35:28 Thread-4124748032 Starting Agent 10.1.0.6.0 from /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1 (00701)
2018-07-31 12:03:41 Thread-4124952832 Starting Agent 10.1.0.6.0 from /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1 (00701)
2018-07-31 14:36:27 Thread-4125055232 Starting Agent 10.1.0.6.0 from /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1 (00701)
2018-07-31 15:23:13 Thread-4124195072 Starting Agent 10.1.0.6.0 from /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1 (00701)
2018-07-31 18:19:37 Thread-4124940544 Starting Agent 10.1.0.6.0 from /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1 (00701)
```

and when i am going to start agent is says agent is already running but while checking status it shows the agent is not running

```
[oracle@vvs ~]$ emctl start agent
TZ set to Asia/Calcutta
Oracle Enterprise Manager 10g Database Control Release 10.2.0.4.0  
Copyright (c) 1996, 2007 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Agent is already running
[oracle@vvs ~]$ emctl status agent
TZ set to Asia/Calcutta
Oracle Enterprise Manager 10g Database Control Release 10.2.0.4.0  
Copyright (c) 1996, 2007 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
---------------------------------------------------------------
Agent is Not Running
```

And when I'm going to start OEM of this instance it failed but the rest of OEM instance stops working

So please let me know how to solve this Problem

edited data

```
2018-08-16 16:47:50 Thread-4090489664 ERROR http: 9: Unable to initialize ssl connection with server, aborting connection attempt

2018-08-16 16:47:50 Thread-4090489664 ERROR pingManager: nmepm_pingReposURL: Cannot connect to https://vvs:5502/em/upload/: retStatus=-1

2018-08-16 16:47:50 Thread-4090489664 ERROR pingManager: Error in updating the agent time stamp file
2018-08-16 16:47:53 Thread-4087339840 ERROR command: nmejcn: error receiving response headers from http://vvs:5502/em/upload/
```

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: FWIW, Oracle 10g was never certified for Linux 7.

Comment: ok right @ EdStevens then why other instance and OEMs are running on same server

Comment: please help....

Comment: Tested on  11g,but you can try  1) emctl stop dbconsole ,2)emctl clearstate agent3)emctl start dbconsole 4)emctl status agent

Comment: @sam emctl clearstate agent failed with error "clearstate failed with ret=-2"

Comment: backup OMS directory in oracle home and follow the steps in section D.4.2.6 "Resetting Enterprise Manager Agent Environment" from this   link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b25414/a_opflex.htm#OIDBI1252 alternativly you can follow steps outlined from this link  http://basklaassen.blogspot.com/2008/07/agent-upload-failsret-2.html .

Comment: tried but result is zero event i tried **emctl upload agent**  but raised error like **EMD upload error: uploadXMLFiles skipped :: OMS version not checked yet.**  and when i m going to stop dbconsole it cant and raised error with **Failed to shutdown DBConsole Gracefully**   and also dropped and recreate the repos but still result is zero

Comment: Check logs in OMS directory and what was the error/erros when you try to start dbconsole?

Comment: please see the edits in question ,content of file is below keyword  **edited data**

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue:

1. Find out which Time Zone the agent is currently configured with.
2. Reset the Time Zone according to Oracle Documentation.

Step 1)

============

```
$ emctl config agent getTZ

Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control Release 11.2.0.3.0
Copyright (c) 1996, 2011 Oracle Corporation. All rights reserved.
GMT-07:00
```

Step 2)

=============

Oracle documentation has described steps for checking and setting EMs' TimeZone:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11857_01/em.111/e16790/ha_agent.htm#BABEFADE